# Sengled Smart Plug with Echo dot

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo, smart-plugs

I bought a Sengled Smart Plug with Echo dot and I tried to connect them.

Alexa found the device and there is a set-up option. I click it and follow instructions.
It's finding the device, connecting, and then it asks for wifi. I choose wifi, put in the password and it tries to connect the plug. It fails and says "something went wrong".

What can I do?

Comment: I wonder if it is a 2.4 GHz Vs 5 issue

Comment: @kalyanswaroop sadly it is not, i use 2.4GHz wifi

Comment: Looking at the Amazon pages, there are 2 versions of the plug. One needs a hub (or the hub in echo plus) which works with 2.4 GHz. The other needs no hub and works with dot, over 5GHz. Is this (no hub needed) the one you bought ? https://a.co/d/eirA20o

Answer (score -1):

Most likely it is Wifi Frequency issue.  It only supports 2.5GHz

> **Wireless Specification**
> Wireless Frequency Range: 2402~2480MHz

From [manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/2294581/Sengled-Sengled-Smart-Plug.html)

You may have to have a different SSID for 2.5 and 5GHz

Comment: Thanks for response. Got two wifi's and am connecting to the one with 2.5GHz in the name so I don't think that's it, sadly. It actually does not even see the other wifi.